# Send JSON data to PHP SERVER (Localhost to Hosting Site)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to send a JSON data to Server(Localhost to Hosting Site), unfortunately it does not work.

I have this code which I found on this site while searching for a solution and modified it a bit.

**proto.html**

This is the button to initiate the function

```
<button onclick="proto_test();">Test Button</button>
```

This is the code for the function that I'm having a problem with.

```
function proto_test() {
var data = {},
data['abc'] = [];
data['abc'].push('some info');
data['abc'].push('some more info');
json_data = JSON.stringify(data);

$.post("proto2.php", {'updateValues': json_data}, function(data) {
alert(data);
});

}
```

**proto2.php**

Here is the code for the php file which that I'm echoing it.

```
<?php
echo $_POST['updateValues'];
?>
```

This is what it looks like after you clicked the button. It alerts the result. 
(LOCALHOST TO LOCALHOST) In other words, I'm using XAMPP.

[image: Result]

Then if I changed the url to pass the data. Which I'm passing it to a SERVER (Hosting Site)
It does not work.

```
$.post("http://www.mysite.com/proto2.php", {'updateValues': json_data}, function(data){
alert(data);
});
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem? I would be glad if someone helps me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the additional note in [jQuery.post() API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). AJAX requests are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). That's why you can't perform ajax post to different domain.

If you have control over the target server, you can [enable cross-origin resource sharing](http://enable-cors.org/). Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7605119/1535679) on how to enable CORS. Note: CORS is not supported in all browsers. See [CORS browser support](http://enable-cors.org/client.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I finished reading the documentation that you provided to me, thanks. Any suggestion for the alternative solution instead of using ajax?

Comment: If you have control over the target server, you can [enable cross-origin resource sharing](http://enable-cors.org/). Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7605119/1535679) on how to enable CORS. Note: CORS is not supported in all browsers. See [CORS browser support](http://enable-cors.org/client.html).